# How to identify a link from href based on string and class name?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get some data from https://betsapi.com/, specifically from the soccer area using python
I saw in the code that the link is dynamic, I mean that a couple of weeks ago it was https://betsapi.com/cin/soccer and now is https://betsapi.com/cip/soccer.

Looking on the code I would like to understand how to identify the current soccer link from this part of code.

```
<div class="card-tabs text-center">
            <a href="/" class="card-tabs-item active">
        All (70)
      </a>
                <a href="/cip/basketball" class="card-tabs-item"></a>
                <a href="/cip/soccer" class="card-tabs-item"></a>
                <a href="/cip/horse-racing" class="card-tabs-item"> </a>
                <a href="/cip/greyhounds" class="card-tabs-item"></a>
                <a href="/cip/ice-hockey" class="card-tabs-item"></a>
                <a href="/cip/table-tennis" class="card-tabs-item"></a>
                <a href="/cip/volleyball" class="card-tabs-item"></a>                                                    
      <div class="dropdown show">
      <a href="#" class="card-tabs-item" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">More</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-menu-arrow show" x-placement="bottom-end" style="position: absolute; transform: translate3d(-109px, 55px, 0px); top: 0px; left: 0px; will-change: transform;">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="/cip/golf"></a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="/cip/tennis"></a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="/cip/baseball"></a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="/cip/esports"></a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="/cip/darts"></a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="/cip/handball"></a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item " href="/cip/futsal"></a>ù
```

Many thanks

Comment: What language?

In jQuery you can find any link containing the term "soccer":

$('a[href*="/soccer/"]').attr('href');

In Python you would use regex to look for the term "soccer". You can also loop through every link and return those containing "soccer".

You want to specify before somebody downvotes you.

Comment: You're right, I'm working on python.

Comment: you can also look for the soccer text using xpath

Comment: If you're using Python, you're going to want to use a tool like [tag:beautifulsoup].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just search through the card tab items and look for `'soccer'`. Then print the href to get the link:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://betsapi.com'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.141 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

cards = soup.find_all('a', {'class':'card-tabs-item'})
soccer = [x for x in cards if 'soccer' in x['href']][0]
link = url + soccer['href']
```

**Output:**

```
print(link)
https://betsapi.com/cip/soccer
```

Answer (score 1):

As alternative you could go with `css selectors` and select `<a>` thats:

- `href` should end with `soccer`:

  ```
  link = url + soup.select_one('a[href$="soccer"]')['href']
  ```

  or more specific:

  ```
  link = url + soup.select_one('a.card-tabs-item[href$="soccer"]')['href']
  ```
- `href` should contain `soccer`:

  ```
  link = url + soup.select_one('a[href*="soccer"]')['href']
  ```

  or more specific:

  ```
  link = url + soup.select_one('a.card-tabs-item[href*="soccer"]')
  ```

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://betsapi.com'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

link = url + soup.select_one('a.card-tabs-item[href$="soccer"]')['href']

print(link)
```

###### Output

```
https://betsapi.com/cip/soccer
```